# Feature request: seeing the reputation on documentation review

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

When reviewing proposed changes for Stack Overflow Documentation, wouldn't it be good to see the reputation of the submitter?

That would allow reviewers to pay more attention if the submitter has low reputation.

Comment: What would that information provide over the actual content?

Comment: Of course, there are low rep experts who will come up with very good documentation, and high rep users who will come up with bad documentation, but this may be an indicator as to how reliable the user is

Answer (score 11):

If you are reviewing an edit, you should pay attention *regardless* of the reputation of the editor. Otherwise, what's the point of reviewing the edit at all?

If we wanted reputation to be used as a metric for how hard you should look at an edit, we would have given high-rep users unreviewed editing access to Docs.SO.

Answer (score 1):

You should approve and/or reject Documentation changes based on merit of the post not user reputation.

Also experts in tags - holders of gold and silver badges can add documentation without going through review process.

[Documentation Proposed Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes)

> Additionally, changes proposed by editors with applicable gold and
>   silver tag badges are immediately approved without further review,
>   unless the change modifies versions or changes which example is
>   pinned.

Having said that, if you are not sure about certain edit just **USE SKIP**. Do not approve or reject changes where you cannot determine how good or bad it is. Especially if edit is of technical nature and you are not expert in the field.